# Tunneling for hydrogen fusion

Tags: temperature, sun, fusion, quantum-tunneling, nucleosynthesis

So I'm trying to find a rough estimate of the temperature required for Hydrogen to turn into Helium through quantum tunneling. In the lecture we were presented with the following:
$$\frac{p^{2}}{2\mu}=\frac{Z_{1}Z_{2}e^{2}}{r}$$
For $p=h/\lambda$ and $\lambda\approx r$ we get:
$$\lambda=\frac{h^{2}}{Z_{1}Z_{2}e^{2}2\mu}$$
Now $$(3/2)k_{B}T=\frac{Z_{1}Z_{2}e^{2}}{\lambda}$$ and if I replace $\lambda$ I get:
$$T=\frac{4\mu Z_{1}^{2}Z_{2}^{2}e^{4}}{3h^{2}k_{B}}$$
If I know replace the constants for the p-p cycle ($Z_{1}=Z_{2}=1, \mu=m_{p}/2$)I get a number which is totally wrong and not $T=10^{7}K$ that is expected. Can anyone tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing your calculations not entirely in the SI system, where the Coulumb potential is $$\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{Z_1Z_2 e^2}{r}.$$
You can see that your $\lambda$ doesn't have units of length, but rather something like $\text{m}^2\cdot\text{kg}\cdot\text{s}^{-4}\cdot\text{A}^{-2}$. Luckily, $\varepsilon_0$ has units of $\frac{\text{F}}{\text{m}}=\text{m}^{-1}\cdot\text{kg}^{-1}\cdot\text{s}^{4}\cdot\text{A}^{2}$ so that obviously fixes the units.

If you include a factor of $(\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0})^2$ (since you use the non-SI Coulomb energy twice) you get [$9.79 * 10^6 \text{K} $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*(proton%20mass%20%2F2)*elementary%20charge%20%5E4%2F(3*planck%20constant%5E2*boltzmann%20constant*(4*pi*vacuum%20permittivity)%5E2)), which is what you want to have.